# How to cross reference a part to all instruction guide pages

Tags: part-identification, instructions

Built my new Millenium Falcon and took it into the office before someone managed to knock it off my desk and onto the floor. It blew up.

Having managed to rebuild it, there are a few pieces left over that I can't figure out where they originally went.

Is there a way for a given piece to find out all the pages in the instruction manual where it is used?

Comment: I don't think such resource exists. Would be great if it did exist but seems to me quite a bit of effort to update such database for every produced set. LEGO is not likely to have or publish such information, so the database would have to be updated manually...

Comment: Related: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10021/how-to-visually-search-for-specific-parts-in-a-3d-model

Comment: Depending on how common is your part, a combination of the PDF manual and 3D models can help. I am looking for tools that can filter and locate parts within the model and indicate them visually.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using the discontinued program *LEGO Digital Designer* where what you want to do can be done with the program's *Selection Tools*.

**BIG NOTE:**  The only thing you'll have to do is to search for your model in *LDD* format.  I'll give you a leg up and [*schmooogle a search string query*](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1&ei=Ps00W9CCPdHZ5gKP3p-IBQ&q=Millenium%20Falcon%20LDD&oq=Millenium%20Falcon%20LDD&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1j0i13i5i30k1l3.63524.64638.0.68847.3.3.0.0.0.0.112.320.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.317...0i10k1j0i8i13i30k1.0.HNTQYt7Q4cU) for you. You'll just have to sift through and find that file.  Good luck!

Okay, Friend, shall we diiiiive in?! RIGHT! LET'S GO!!

I'm gonna step through the motions using a model comparable to the size of your busted up Falcon.

*[Schmooogle](https://www.google.com/search?q=Millenium%20Falcon%20how%20many%20pieces&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1)* says there are 7,541 pieces in *MF*, so we have to go big with *Super Mario Bros. End Stage Castle* which pieces out at 7,994 bricks.
[image: Super Mario Bros. End Stage Castle]

1)  First let's imagine it was knocked off it's perch:(

2)  Painstakingly rebuild what we can, but... huh, we got extras?... F***!!

3)  We got 5 stragglers in hand...err empty blue glove:
[image]

- a red inverted slope,
- a 1x1 white brick with a hole in it,
- a yellow 1x1 tile stuck to a yellow 1x1 plate,
- and finally a 2x3 brown brick.

4)  Open your model in LDD.
[image: Opened in LDD]

5)  Use the menu and place a digital copy of each extra real-life piece at the bottom of your model all in a nice neat little row.
[image: ducks in a row]

6)  Okay, zoom out a little.  One at a time using the "Shape and Color" Selection Tool, click on each extra piece to highlight all bricks in your model that has that same shape and color.
[image]

7)  To see those pieces visually unhindered by other bricks, click "Invert" selection to highlight everything that wasn't originally highlighted. 
[image: Highlighted inverted selection of bricks]

8)  Then hide those obstructing bricks by clicking the "Hide" selection tool.
[image: Hide everything but red bricks]

9) For remaining bricks:

Lather, [image]

Rinse,[image]

and Repeat.[image]

Whoa! That's a lot of 2x3 bricks!.  In cases like this you might have to practice up , and do some old school find the difference picture comparisons, and get yourself geared up to find that missing hole in your model.  Good luck!

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image: ![You Just Got Troll Fished!]
Here! Enjoy a troll fish...lol!  Peace!

Comment: Wow! Amazing what can be done with that software; nice tutorial on how to "reverse-engineer" to find where the missing pieces go.