# How to visually search for specific parts in a 3D model?

Tags: building, software, tools

For a missed/loose piece that needs to be reattached, I plan to check all the steps where the piece was used. If I can also get an overview of the possible piece locations from the existing 3D models, that should speed things up as well. However, I don't see any option to filter/show by piece in Mecabricks or LDD. Is there any other way?

Comment: If you're trying to reattach one piece to a single set, I would advise you to let us know in your question which set and part you're trying to reattach. If you're just asking to find out if there is a function to search for part usage during building, hopefully someone answers you soon :)

Comment: @SlicksterTheBrickster It was something from 75192..figured it out in the end by careful backtracking. I did not specify any model so that the question can be more useful to others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay Bro, here we go.  I still use LEGO Digital Designer.  Open it, and you'll be using a combination of a few tools to filter out the exact piece locations in your model's 3 dimensional space.

Below we'll use pictures of Bowser as an example for a few selections.
[image]

The "Selection" tool sub tools:

1. Single Selection: Pick one piece you want to move.
2. Multiple Selection: Pick multiple pieces you want to move. Shortcut Key:  Hold down control button to to select multiple pieces.
3. Connected Selection: Move the pieces that interlock in a continuous cluster. (VERY USEFUL FOR ME!)
4. Color: Pick a specific color.
5. Shape: Pick a specific shape REGARDLESS of color.
6. Color and Shape: Pick a specific shape and color.

A combination of two other tools that will bring it all together is the "Invert" Selection Tool and the "Hide" Section tool.

Connected + Hide Example:

In this example of "Connected" Selection, look at Bowser's toes.  They're not highlighted, which means they are not connected, but after we hit the "Hide" button we see a green piece of Bowser's chest just a floatin' too.
[image]
Connected.

[image]
Hidden.

Multiple Shape + Invert + Hide + Shape and Color Example:

I buy my models on Bricklink.com but have to upload them through Stud.io, but Stud.io doesn't recognize which 1x1 tiles LEGO Digital Designer is using.  So, I have to filter them out regardless of color, and figure out how many of each color I need to manually add them to my purchase later.
[image]
Selection of 1x1 tile regardless of color.

[image]
Invert Selection.

[image]
Hide non 1x1 tiles.

[image]
Specific Color and Shape for PINK.  Lower left corner tells me exact amount I need in this color.

[image]
Specific Color and Shape for GREEN.  Lower left corner tells me exact amount I need in this color.

[image]
Specific Color and Shape for TAN.  Lower left corner tells me exact amount I need in this color.

With these combinations you should be able quickly see and fix your shit!  Good luck and Later!

[image]

Comment: invert selection is the key here, very good explanation of LDD functionality which I had no idea of